# hadoop nodemanager killed by SIGSEGV

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

every time I execute a big hive query, my hadoop nodemanager killed by SEGSEGV. I'm using hadoop 2.8.0 and oracle jdk 1.8.0_131

The yarn java error file snippet as follow:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f4b766818b1, pid=10904, tid=0x00007f4b33fff700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_131-b11) (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.131-b11 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libc.so.6+0x1628b1]  __strlen_sse2_pminub+0x11
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007f4b727d2800):  JavaThread "ContainersLauncher #10" [_thread_in_native, id=16663, stack(0x00007f4b33eff000,0x00007f4b34000000)]

siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr: 0x000000000000000f

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000000, RBX=0x00000000000000b3, RCX=0x000000000000000f, RDX=0x0000000000000006
RSP=0x00007f4b33ffbdf8, RBP=0x00007f4b381b7e70, RSI=0x00007f4b33ffc2d0, RDI=0x000000000000000f
R8 =0x00007f4b33ffbe60, R9 =0x0000000000000008, R10=0x00000000fffff000, R11=0x00007f4b766963f4
R12=0x0000000000000022, R13=0x00007f4b381b7f10, R14=0x00007f4b77123840, R15=0x0000000000000004
RIP=0x00007f4b766818b1, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010283, CSGSFS=0x0000000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000004
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00007f4b33ffbdf8)
0x00007f4b33ffbdf8:   00007f4b76f1cbed 0000000000000000
0x00007f4b33ffbe08:   00007f4b33ffc6d0 00007f4b33ffc6d0
0x00007f4b33ffbe18:   00007f4b76f200e4 00007f4b76f200ed
0x00007f4b33ffbe28:   00007f4b33ffbe60 00000000016f0520
0x00007f4b33ffbe38:   00007f4b33ffbed0 0000000000000004
0x00007f4b33ffbe48:   00007f4b76f1bbe8 00007f4b33ffc6d0
0x00007f4b33ffbe58:   00007f4b33ffc2d0 00656e696c646d63
0x00007f4b33ffbe68:   0000000000000000 333030305f363938
0x00007f4b33ffbe78:   303030304bb40058 0000000000000000
0x00007f4b33ffbe88:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007f4b33ffbe98:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007f4b33ffbea8:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007f4b33ffbeb8:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007f4b33ffbec8:   0000000000000000 6d616e6500203a5d
0x00007f4b33ffbed8:   0000000000003a65 0000000000000000
0x00007f4b33ffbee8:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007f4b33ffbef8:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007f4b33ffbf08:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007f4b33ffbf18:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007f4b33ffbf28:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007f4b33ffbf38:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007f4b33ffbf48:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007f4b33ffbf58:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007f4b33ffbf68:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007f4b33ffbf78:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007f4b33ffbf88:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007f4b33ffbf98:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007f4b33ffbfa8:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007f4b33ffbfb8:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007f4b33ffbfc8:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007f4b33ffbfd8:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007f4b33ffbfe8:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000 

Instructions: (pc=0x00007f4b766818b1)
0x00007f4b76681891:   c0 c3 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 0f 1f 00 48
0x00007f4b766818a1:   31 c0 89 f9 83 e1 3f 66 0f ef c0 83 f9 30 77 1d
0x00007f4b766818b1:   f3 0f 6f 0f 66 0f 74 c1 66 0f d7 d0 85 d2 0f 85
0x00007f4b766818c1:   4e 02 00 00 48 89 f8 48 83 e0 f0 eb 24 48 89 f8 

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RBX=0x00000000000000b3 is an unknown value
RCX=0x000000000000000f is an unknown value
RDX=0x0000000000000006 is an unknown value
RSP=0x00007f4b33ffbdf8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f4b727d2800
RBP=0x00007f4b381b7e70 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f4b73bd4800
RSI=0x00007f4b33ffc2d0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f4b727d2800
RDI=0x000000000000000f is an unknown value
R8 =0x00007f4b33ffbe60 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f4b727d2800
R9 =0x0000000000000008 is an unknown value
R10=0x00000000fffff000 is an unknown value
R11=0x00007f4b766963f4: <offset 0x1773f4> in /lib64/libc.so.6 at 0x00007f4b7651f000
R12=0x0000000000000022 is an unknown value
R13=0x00007f4b381b7f10 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f4b73bd4800
R14=0x00007f4b77123840: snoopy_inputdatastorage_data+0 in /usr/local/snoopy/lib/libsnoopy.so at 0x00007f4b76f16000
R15=0x0000000000000004 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x00007f4b33eff000,0x00007f4b34000000],  sp=0x00007f4b33ffbdf8,  free space=1011k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libc.so.6+0x1628b1]  __strlen_sse2_pminub+0x11

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(I[B[B[BI[BI[B[IZ)I+0
j  java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>([B[BI[BI[B[IZ)V+30
j  java.lang.ProcessImpl.start([Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/ProcessBuilder$Redirect;Z)Ljava/lang/Process;+433
j  java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start()Ljava/lang/Process;+161
j  org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand()V+136
j  org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run()V+23
j  org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute()V+67
j  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(Lorg/apache/hadoop/yarn/server/nodemanager/executor/ContainerStartContext;)I+492
j  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call()Ljava/lang/Integer;+1166
j  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
J 4490 C1 java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run()V (126 bytes) @ 0x00007f4b5e50acdc [0x00007f4b5e50aa80+0x25c]
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Ljava/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker;)V+95
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()V+5
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
```

the completed log can be downloaded here [yarn_hs_error.log](https://ufile.io/yoryl)

it seems like a hadoop or jdk bug?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved the problem, it's because snoopy, I disable it and it works good now.

```
/usr/local/snoopy/sbin/snoopy-disable
```